# Open layer 3 click on layer best practice

Tags: openlayers-3

I am new to OL.

I need to implement a logic that should happen if I pressed on a specific item in a specific layer.

I have to state that I'm not writing a project from scratch, and I actually inherited a very basic but complex system.

The system gets the layers from MapGuide 2.5.

This is how the map is initiated:

```
 var map = new ol.Map({
            loadTilesWhileInteracting:true,
            layers: this.layers,
            target: this._element[0],
            controls: controls,
            interactions: interactions,
            view: view
        });

 view.fit(that.extent, map.getSize());
```

I tried adding a select interaction - it didn't work (my promise was never called).

```
var select_interaction = new ol.interaction.Select();

select_interaction.getFeatures().on("add", function (e) { 
     var feature = e.element; //the feature selected
});

map.addInteraction(select_interaction);
```

I tried:

```
map.on('click', function (evt) {
            var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
              function (feature, layer) {
                  debugger;
                  this.log("fff")
              });
        });
```

In this case, the promise works but I get no features.

**EDIT:**

I also tried:

```
var feature = map.forEachLayerAtPixel(evt.pixel,
              function (feature, layer) {..}
```

but I get the exception:

```
uncaught security error:  Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.  ol.js:341
```

How can I do this?

Thanks,
Ido

Comment: Do you actually load any vector layers?

Comment: I dont know, the layer is selctable according to mapguide. How can I tell?

Comment: Layer types are roughly separated in two categories in OL. Image layers (tiles etc.) and vector layers. You have to inspect the contents of this.layers that you pass as an argument in the constructor of the map and see what type of layers it contains. You can only interact *directly* with vector type layers.

Comment: I am trying to inspect but I get wired objects - there are 2 layers [SL, H] and when I open them I get more letters. This is weird.

Comment: I think all my layers are image layers.
What can I do?

Comment: Where does this.layers gets it's value in the original source? You cannot use the inspector to browse through the properties of OL objects, because it's compiled & minified. You could do `map.getLayers().item(0)` and so on to access individual layers however.

Comment: Now if all the layers you have are image layers (such as WMS), you need server side functionality to pick a shape / object.

Comment: I tried using: map.forEachLayerAtPixel (instead of map.forEachFeature) and I get this exception: SecurityError -  Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data. ol.js:341.  Any ideas?

Comment: @kagelos Your comment was really useful!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error while I was trying to loop through layers at pixel via `forEachLayerAtPixel` method.

Thanks to @kagelos comment, I managed to solve the problem simply by filtering the layers and looping through only *Vector* layers.

> Layer types are roughly separated in two categories in OL. Image layers (tiles etc.) and vector layers. You have to inspect the contents of this.layers that you pass as an argument in the constructor of the map and see what type of layers it contains. You can only interact directly with vector type layers.

Here is the final code:

```
Map.forEachLayerAtPixel( cursorPosition, function ( _layer ) {

  // you will get the vector layer here

}, this, function ( _layer ) {

    if ( _layer instanceof ol.layer.Vector ) {
        return true;
    }
});
```